# Print data in console with Observable - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

Trying to learn Observable's in angular 2 and I can't seem to get something simple as printing keyup inputs from an text input field to work. Here is the code from my app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `    
               <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
    `
})
export class AppComponent{
    constructor() {

        var input = $('#search');

        var keyups = Observable.fromEvent(input, 'keyup');

        keyups.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Angular 2 version of what you are trying to achieve.

```
  import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `    
                <input #search id="search" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
      `
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('search') search: ElementRef;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      Observable.fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, 'keyup')
        .subscribe((data: KeyboardEvent) => console.log(data.key));
    }
  }
```

The main change is to use a template syntax and ViwChild to get hold of the element in the component. See the docs [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) for more. Also [this](http://angularjs.blogspot.jp/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html) blog post is helpful on avoiding common mistakes when getting started. If there were to be a sixth mistake to avoid to add to the list I think it should be don't use jQuery with Angular2.

Comment: Thank you so much, the tutorials I have been following seem to be outdated! thanks for your awesome explanation ill be sure to read up.

Comment: No problem. I forgot to add another resource. The [AngularConnect](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzrskTiT_ObAk3xBkVxMz5g) YouTube channel is good for staying up to date with the latest changes.

Comment: Awesome mate pitty I dont have someone like you as a mentor haha !